# Launching zypper command with root privilege

Tags: linux, permissions, root, zypper

I want to initiate zypper command without the entry of sudo.
For example,

```
zypper update
```

I attempt to change the permission bit of the zypper file located at /usr/bin folder. I assume that with allow me to run the zypper command without sudo command.

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root root 1942112 Oct 10 19:21 /usr/bin/zypper
```

I added current user to root group; this file should be able to run as root.

Comment: You made the file setgid, yet group `root` is just an ordinary group. And adding the current user to group `root` is useless. Do you understand what the [setuid and setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bits do?

Comment: I assume that the file will be ran as root group. which means it can bypass root privelege

Comment: From where did you get the impression that membership in the group `root` confers any special privileges? Can you provide a quotation?

Comment: strange, I added setuid instead, and it works. I assume that the error is related to root UID.

Comment: If that is the case, It would be unsafe. Anyone can login to my machine and execute command.

Comment: @AlexP Make that an answer so that this question does not look unsolved any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> strange, I added setuid instead, and it works.

For a binary to run with root privileges when invoked by any other user, it **must** be setuid.  You can do it as follows:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/chmod 4755 /usr/bin/zypper
```